# All ways in which $S_{4}$ acts on a set with two elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I am looking at $S_{4}$, the set of permutations of the integers $\{1,2,3,4\}$, which has $4!$ elements. I am trying to describe all ways in which $S_{4}$ acts on a set with two elements, say $S = \{a,b\}$. I know that the only subgroup of order $12$ of the symmetric group $S_{4}$ is the alternating group $A_{4}$, but I do not know how to specifically apply this to this problem.

**Approach**: Let f: $S_{4}$ -> $S_{2}$. |im f| = 2 or 1, so then |ker f| = |$S_{4}$|/|im f| = 24/2 = 12 or = 24. im f is a subgroup of $S_{4}$ so im f is $A_{4}$ or $S_{4}$. I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: Note, this is the same as asking the set of group homomorphisms $S_4\to S_2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you. Are there very many of them? I can't imagine there are more than 10-20 of them

Comment: What can be the kernel? How big must the kernel be?

Comment: Is the kernel K = {1} since only e in $S_{4}$ can be mapped to the identity in $S_{2}$, so phi is injective where phi is the map?

Comment: Can any map from $S_4$ to $S_2$ be injective? $S_4/\ker(\phi)$ is isomorphic to the image of $\phi$, which is a subgroup of $S_2$.

Comment: No it cannot be injective sorry, so the order of the kernel must be larger than one

Comment: Are there just 2 group homomorphisms then? I know that S4 acts on S2 so there is a homomorphism that exists that is not injective

Comment: Or is $S_{4}$ = K$S_{2}$ where K is the kernel